# How do we manipulate the first bit of a u8 array in Rust?

Tags: arrays, rust, bit-manipulation, byte, bit

I'm trying to make an asynchronous WebSocket server (my own implementation). I have the following code:

```
use tokio::net::TcpListener;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let mut listener = TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1:8080").await?;

    loop {
        let (socket, _) = listener.accept().await?;

        tokio::spawn(async move {
            let mut buffer = [0u8; 512];
            let stuff = match socket.read(&mut buffer).await {
                Ok(n) => buffer[..n].to_vec(),
                Err(_) => return,
            };
        });
    }
}
```

Now what do I do? According to the spec, I have to check the FIN bit, opcode, etc. but how do I do that. The FIN bit is just 1 bit, how are we supposed to get that out of a u8 array? Examples would help greatly.

Comment: To be clear, is your question just about how to read the first bit of a `u8` array? If so, there is a lot of noise in your question, related to Websocket specifics, which is not relevant if you just need to know how to read the bit.

Comment: @PeterHall Yeah, I just thought there was this lingering possibility that I interpreted the specification incorrectly. I'll edit the question

Comment: Your interpretation of [the spec](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455#section-5.2) seems correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read the first bit from a byte buffer, you could use something like this:

```
fn fin_bit(buffer: &[u8]) -> Option<bool> {
    buffer.get(0)
        .map(|first_byte| first_byte & 0b10000000 > 0)
}
```

Comment: What about writing?

Comment: @MOHAMEDALSANALI If you have follow-up questions, ask a new question instead of commenting on an existing one.

Comment: I just thought it would be more convenient for people looking for this if instructions on how to read AND write the first bit were in the same question. I'll edit my question to ask for this as well